# How to set random intervals for request in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I have a question about how to set a random interval between requests. For example I want to send a request every X seconds and X < 30s. Maybe 25s or 29s. Which timer should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `Gaussian Random Timer` by setting Deviation and Constant delay.

[image]

Comment: How can I set the Deviation if the X>30s?

Comment: What do you mean? why X is > 30s ?
If your goal to add delay less than 30s, then you want to add something like:
`delay.variable + delay.constant < 30s`. Keep in mind the timer has the values in milliseconds.

Comment: glad to help! happy testing.